# undefined method `has_one_attached' - Spree, AWS S3, Product Images, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, amazon-s3, spree, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm trying to connect my Spree shopping cart with AWS S3 for product image uploads but I keep getting the error:

```
.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `m
ethod_missing': undefined method `has_one_attached'
```

Here is my set-up:

Gemfile

```
ruby '2.4.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'spree', '~> 3.6.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.3'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.3'
gem 'globalize', github: 'globalize/globalize'
gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_i18n'
gem 'spree_globalize', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_globalize', branch: 'master'
gem 'spree_static_content', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_static_content'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
```

config/initializers/spree.rb

```
attachment_config = {

    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      bucket:            ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
    },

    storage:        :s3,
    s3_region:      ENV['S3_REGION'],
    s3_headers:     { "Cache-Control" => "max-age=31557600" },
    s3_protocol:    "https",
    bucket:         ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    url:            ":s3_domain_url",

    styles: {
        mini:     "48x48>",
        small:    "100x100>",
        product:  "240x240>",
        large:    "600x600>"
    },

    path:           "/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    default_url:    "/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    default_style:  "product"
  }

  attachment_config.each do |key, value|
    Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][key.to_sym] = value
  end
```

Has anyone come across this error and has a solution?

Comment: having the same problem. Can anyone give a hand with this?

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: Did anyone manage to get a solution to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having this problem in the future, this is how I've fixed it.

If you are editing the Spree::User class as an initializer, the problem is that the initializer from 'active_storage/reflection' did not run. So add these lines at the beggining of your class_eval block:

```
include ActiveStorage::Reflection::ActiveRecordExtensions

ActiveRecord::Reflection.singleton_class.prepend(ActiveStorage::Reflection::ReflectionExtension)

include ActiveStorage::Attached::Model
```

Afterwards, ActiveStorage should be loaded and you will be able to find the method `has_one_attached :image`

Answer (score 0):

Comment lines `attachment_config` in spree.rb

> Declare Active Storage services in `config/storage.yml`. For each service your application uses, provide a name and the requisite configuration.

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: ""
  secret_access_key: ""
  bucket: ""
  region: "" # e.g. 'us-east-1'
```

> To use the Amazon S3 service in production, you add the following to `config/environments/production.rb`:

`config.active_storage.service = :amazon`

> Add the `aws-sdk-s3` gem to your Gemfile:

`gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false`

Source: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup

Answer (score -1):

That config doesn't work for me as well. Actually the steps are pretty straightforward.
Declare the amazon configurations in storage.yml, add the aws gem and you are ready to go. ActiveStorage documentations has it all. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup