Super odd sidekiq behavior, stops parsing file/loading methods at "has_one_attached"
I have a large Rails app I've been working on for a while... I started noticing some incredibly odd behavior recently.  Just to note, this is Rails 6.1.7.8 and Sidekiq 7.3.1...
Basically I started noticing in production that one of my ActiveRecord objects would load in Sidekiq jobs, but I was getting lots of NoMethodErrors on the records, even though the methods were clearly defined in my model.  After tons of logging and testing, I noticed that methods after my has_one_attached :pdf line were getting the NoMethodError, while everything before that is working just fine...
Sidekiq isn't throwing any errors at load.  Calling MyJob.new.perform works just fine, but when the job is queued up and executed by Sidekiq, the methods after has_one_attached always fail.  In other files, it doesn't cause any issues.  It's driving me mad.

Is there an error message when the job fails? Please share the error message and the stack trace. What does the model look like, the job, and the code that enqueues the job?

Can you reproduce the issue when running Sidekiq locally? What about running the worker from the Rails console?

Stefan, yes I get the same issue locally in Sidekiq when running in production mode. If I run the worker directly from Rails console (ie: MyJob.new.perform) I do not get an error. It’s driving me mad

Spicker - the error in the job is the NoMethodError mentioned in the question… Any method defined after the has_one_attached throws the error when called only within a Sidekiq job. Calling directly in console works.
I also tried creating a new dummy job and do not get the error. I’m thinking it maybe has something to do with the schema of the model in question. I’ll post more tomorrow… just landed after a full day of travel.

Theoretically, if an exceptions occurs in the class body (let's say because has_one_attached isn't defined or properly configured), and that exception gets rescued and not reported for whatever reason, the class would be defined up to that point. It's merely a guess, but you could try wrapping that line (or even the entire class definition) into a begin-rescue-end block to rescue and log the exception yourself. Maybe also add some debug output at certain points within the class body to see how far it gets evaluated.

I finally found the issue -- when wrapping w/ begin/rescue I just saw "undefined method has_one_attached"... I found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213386/undefined-method-has-one-attached-for-class-nomethoderror-using-ubuntu and was able to implement their solution... Basically an initializer was referencing the class before the injection!

I finally found the issue -- when wrapping w/ begin/rescue I just saw "undefined method has_one_attached"... I found this thread: stackoverflow.com/questions/55213386/… and was able to implement their solution... Basically an initializer was referencing the class before the injection!
